# fatal exception in android

Tags: android

i have written simple client server socket programming code as follow

MyServer.java

```
 import java.io.DataInputStream;
 import java.io.DataOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.net.ServerSocket;
 import java.net.Socket;


 public class MyServer {

   public static void main(String[] args){
   ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
   Socket socket = null;
   DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
   DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

    try {
         serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
         System.out.println("Listening :8888");
        } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

   while(true){
    try {
    socket = serverSocket.accept();
    dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println("ip: " + socket.getInetAddress());
    System.out.println("message: " + dataInputStream.readUTF());
    dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Hello!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   finally{
   if( socket!= null){
 try {
  socket.close();
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
}

if( dataInputStream!= null){
 try {
  dataInputStream.close();
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
}

if( dataOutputStream!= null){
 try {
  dataOutputStream.close();
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  }
 }
 }}
```

android client is as follows

MyClientActivity.java

```
package com.exercise.AndroidClient;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyClientActivity extends Activity {
EditText textOut;
TextView textIn;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     textOut = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textout);
     Button buttonSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
     textIn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textin);
     buttonSend.setOnClickListener(buttonSendOnClickListener);
 }

 Button.OnClickListener buttonSendOnClickListener
 = new Button.OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 Socket socket = null;
 DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
 DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

 try {
  socket = new Socket("113.193.42.220", 8888);
  dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
  dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
  dataOutputStream.writeUTF(textOut.getText().toString());
  textIn.setText(dataInputStream.readUTF());
 } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 finally{
  if (socket != null){
   try {
    socket.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }

  if (dataOutputStream != null){
   try {
    dataOutputStream.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }

  if (dataInputStream != null){
   try {
    dataInputStream.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 }
}};
 }
```

Main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >
 <TextView
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/hello"
 />
 <EditText
 android:id="@+id/textout"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
 <Button
 android:id="@+id/send"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Send"
 />
 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/textin"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
 </LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.exercise.AndroidClient"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyClientActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I am getting FatalException on execution of client.pls suggest me how to handle this.
i have tried my pc's ip address and 127.0.0.1 also so do i have any problem with ip address or anything else is causing FatalException pls help me out.

logcat is as follow

```
02-21 21:05:48.793: D/gralloc_goldfish(553): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-21 21:08:39.794: D/AndroidRuntime(553): Shutting down VM
02-21 21:08:39.794: W/dalvikvm(553): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
02-21 21:08:39.824: E/AndroidRuntime(553): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 21:08:39.824: E/AndroidRuntime(553): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-21 21:08:39.824: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
02-21 21:08:39.824: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
02-21 21:08:39.824: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
02-21 21:08:39.824: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
02-21 21:08:39.824: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
02-21 21:08:39.824: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
02-21 21:08:39.824: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
02-21 21:08:39.824: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:127)
02-21 21:08:39.824: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:177)
02-21 21:08:39.824: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:149)
02-21 21:08:39.824: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at com.exercise.AndroidClient.MyClientActivity$1.onClick(MyClientActivity.java:44)
02-21 21:08:39.824: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
02-21 21:08:39.824: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
02-21 21:08:39.824: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-21 21:08:39.824: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-21 21:08:39.824: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-21 21:08:39.824: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-21 21:08:39.824: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 21:08:39.824: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-21 21:08:39.824: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-21 21:08:39.824: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-21 21:08:39.824: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are acessing network on main application thread. This is not allowed in Android 3+. You need to start separate thread do access network.

You can use `AsyncTask` to separate your code, which is acessing network, to another `Thread`.

Comment: Yes, you can access network from main app thread in versions, prior to 3.0. But it is not recommended as it can lead to 'Application Not Responding' dialog and poor application UI perfomance.