# Android HTTP POST request error - socket failed EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to send a POST request to my localhost from an Android app under [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29), but I am receiving this error:

> socket failed EACCES (Permission denied).

I'm doing this through the apache.commons library. I've tried to connect via HttpClient before, but there was a similar error:

> Connect to **myhost** refused.

Here is the code:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entry_login);
        userLogin = login.getText().toString();

        pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entry_password);
        userPwd = pwd.getText().toString();

        BufferedReader br = null;

        HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();

        PostMethod method = new PostMethod("http://127.0.0.1/testPost.php");
        method.addParameter("name", "Arthur");

        System.out.println("Login: " + userLogin);

        try {
            httpclient.executeMethod(method);

            int returnCode = httpclient.executeMethod(method);

            if (returnCode == HttpStatus.SC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED) {
                System.err.println("The Post method is not implemented by this URI");

                // Still consume the response body
                method.getResponseBodyAsString();
            }
            else {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(method.getResponseBodyAsStream()));
                String readLine;
                while (((readLine = br.readLine()) != null)) {
                    System.err.println(readLine);
                }
            }

            /* List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Arthur"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("OP_ID", "10001"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IP_ADDRESS", "127.0.0.1"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FIELDS=field100", userLogin + "&field101=" + userPwd));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("REQ_TYPE=", "26"));
            */

            System.out.println("http connection done well!");
            // response.getStatusLine();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            method.releaseConnection();
            if (br != null)
                try {
                    br.close();
                }
                catch (Exception fe) {

                }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Do you have INTERNET permissions in your manifest?

Check your `AndroidManifest.xml` for the followinf lines

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Good advise dude the previous error message is gone, but NullPointerException actual now =), 1 point to U.

Comment: There is an error FATAL EXCEPTION: main; android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException; android.BlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork etc I think that the emulator still blocking request through sockets...

Comment: On NetworkOnMainThreadException see my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380166/fatal-exception-in-android/9380512#9380512

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to connect to your local machine?  I think instead of 127.0.0.1 it should be `10.0.2.2`

See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

Comment: Thanks for advise, but it didn`t work for me - the same message appeared. Also I wonder how to send POST request to other "real" hosts (not only to local)?