# Android socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied) error

Tags: android, sockets, permissions

I am getting an error " socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)" while trying to connect using HttpURLConnection object to the localhost.I read related questions on stackoverflow such as [Android HTTP POST request error - socket failed EACCES (Permission denied)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461953/android-http-post-request-error-socket-failed-eacces-permission-denied). But I have added all permission to the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

related part of my code

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            URL url=new URL("http://192.168.23.1/sozluk/cek.php");
            HttpURLConnection urlConn=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            urlConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConn.connect();

            InputStream iStream=urlConn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));


            StringBuilder strBuffer=new StringBuilder();

            String strread=null;
            while((strread=reader.readLine())!=null){

                strBuffer.append(strread);
            }

            reader.close();

            String result=strBuffer.toString();
            Log.v("result",result);
            return result;


        } catch ( Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }
```

Logcat output

```
    java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
    06-29 01:39:31.956  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:583)
    06-29 01:39:31.961  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:201)
    06-29 01:39:31.961  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.checkOpenAndCreate(Socket.java:663)
    06-29 01:39:31.961  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:807)
    06-29 01:39:31.961  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76)
    06-29 01:39:31.961  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
    06-29 01:39:31.961  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
    06-29 01:39:31.961  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
    06-29 01:39:31.961  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
    06-29 01:39:31.961  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
    06-29 01:39:31.961  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
    06-29 01:39:31.961  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
    06-29 01:39:31.961  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
    06-29 01:39:31.961  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
    06-29 01:39:31.961  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ at com.foo.foo.MasterActivity$WordLoader.doInBackground(MasterActivity.java:59)
    06-29 01:39:31.961  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ at com.foo.foo.MasterActivity$WordLoader.doInBackground(MasterActivity.java:50)
    06-29 01:39:31.961  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    06-29 01:39:31.961  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    06-29 01:39:31.966  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    06-29 01:39:31.966  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    06-29 01:39:31.966  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    06-29 01:39:31.966  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    06-29 01:39:31.966  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    06-29 01:39:31.966  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
    06-29 01:39:31.966  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
    06-29 01:39:31.966  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:181)
    06-29 01:39:31.966  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:568)
    06-29 01:39:31.966  11459-11474/com.foo.foo W/System.err﹕ ... 22 more
```

Comment: Where are you placing the permisions? This need to be above that application tag

Comment: Why are you talking about localhost? You use emulator or a device?

Comment: @Santiago Solved. I had put them into the application tag. Thank you